# MongoError: Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to insert aggregated result into some collection . And in output collection one column has unique index
I am doing all this in mongoose.

```
await mongoose.connection.collections['inputcollection'].createIndexes({ "uniquecolumnname": 1 }, { "unique": true});

await inputcollection.aggregate(([{ "$addFields": {"uniquecolumnname": "$username"} }, { $merge: { into: "outputcollection", on: "uniquecolumnname", whenMatched: "replace", whenNotMatched: "insert" } }])).exec();
```

But I am getting error MongoError: Cannot find index to verify that join fields will be unique

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

From your first command looks like you are creating an index on the `inputcollection` but you are trying to merge result to your `outputcollection` which doesn't seem to contain a unique   index.

Verify the unique index you are creating resides on the collection the results are being merged into.